# A number sum in Excel yields a date

Tags: excel

I have eight items, the second row is the date, the third row is the price. However, when I try to sum the eight elements of the third row the output is a date. How come? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Could you put some sample data that you're trying to add?

Answer (score 1):

Just reformat the cell by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `1`